# Tracking when a number of NSURLSessions have completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

This has perplexed me for some time now so any advice would be appreciated.

I have 10 `NSURLSessionUploadTasks` started at the same time and happening asynchronously from my `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self uploadMainInformation];
[self uploadSubInformation];
[self uploadLocation];
[self uploadMainPhoto];
[self uploadSubPhoto1];
[self uploadSubPhoto2];
```

etc. I am using an array to say when the tasks are complete by using completion handlers. However, I'm stumped as to how to poll the array to find out when it is empty. Adding and removing at the start and end of each session start and end is easy. I just have no idea how to poll for an empty array.

Is it possible to track when the `NSMutableArray` is empty? Or is there a better solution of which I don't know and can't seem to find? I simply wish to start 10 simultaneous uploads and know when they have all (successfully) completed.

Thanks in advance for any assistance. It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complicated with the array? Just add a counter, a simple int, increment it when you fire a request and decrement it when a request is finished or ran into an error. They are all complete when the value of your counter is back to 0.

Anyway, an `NSArray` is empty when its `count` method returns 0.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using BOOLs at the moment but don't know when all the uploads are complete. If I start them all at the same time, how do I monitor the int's to know when it's reached zero? If I'm making any sense?

Comment: Your question and my answer is so horribly basic that I fear you want to ask for something else. Are you comfortable with the completion handler concept? Completion handlers are often given as inline blocks. That is a piece of code that is executed when the request is finished. There you should not only decrement the int value but even check it for zero after it was decremented. Or use the `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` delegate method for that.

Comment: If you want more control about the individual session task objects, that are currently 'on the air' then you could still use your array. Better, I think, would be just an NSSet into which you can simply add the task object itself and in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` or in the completion handler you just remove it from the set. When the set is empty (count == 0) then you are done.

Comment: My question is too basic. I'll update it shortly. Your answers are greatly appreciated. I always think myself a pretty good programmer but the basics throw me. I am using completion handlers now to tell me when each task is complete. So no problems with adding or removing things to arrays or int's. If I start all 10 uploads simultaneously I need to know when they have all finished. I know this is when the int gets to zero, but how do I keep polling the value of the int to know when it is zero. I hope that makes it clearer. I'm feeling so stupid at the moment.

Comment: Well, if I got that question right, then you'll have to do that within the completion handler too. You can (I'm only 99% positive about that) call any method of the class in which the block, that is handed over as completion handler, is coded. You you could define your own callback method does the check for zero and all subsequent processing when the value of 0 is reached. So you don't have to repeat the same lines in each of the completion handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Set a delegate on your `NSURLSession`, and add the method:

```
- (void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session;
```